# Android emulator not loading I'm my android studio

Tags: android-emulator

I installed android studio recently and I set up and emulator(an android 14 emulator to be specific) but when I try to run the emulator, it just shows the Google logo and never comes on.

I never got to open any apps on the emulator. I don't know whether it is because of my laptop specs or not

I have a 4GB ram and my laptop speed is about 2.45ghz